# Why Doesn't this equation work?

Tags: pi

$$\frac{n2^nn!^2}{(2n)!}$$

Is supposed to output the n<sup>th</sup> decimal of pi, this works fine with $$n = 1$$, but why not with $$n = 2$$? (I ommited the sigma, equation was found [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_pi))

Comment: It looks like that equation pushes out digits of pi in a different base than base $10$.

Comment: Nope, it says "Simon Plouffe derived an algorithm to extract the nth decimal digit of π (using base 10 math to extract a base 10 digit),"

Comment: @Jonny I don't think this is the equation for extracting base 10 digits. Underneath the formula in question it is stated "This formula permits one to fairly readily compute the kth binary or hexadecimal digit of π, without having to compute the preceding k − 1 digits."

Comment: @user137794 So then what is?

Answer (score 1):

That equation is not any digit extraction formula for π, it is the expression for π that Plouffe began with to develop his decimal digit extraction algorithm.  For an equation to correspond directly to a digit extraction algorithm it must be a [BBP-type forumla](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBP-TypeFormula.html), which have this form:
$$\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{f(k)}{b^k}}$$

The original [BBP formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) is a digit extraction formula for π, but with $b=16$, so it extracts hexadecimal digits, not decimal digits.  Plouffe (the 'P' in BBP) did publish a decimal digit extraction algorithm, but it does not correspond to a BBP-type formula.

[Plouffe's paper (2009 reprint)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0303) is focused on the underlying principles, and does not give a straightforward description of the algorithm.  The 2009 reprint references two improved decimal digit extraction algorithms, which have somewhat clearer descriptions:

- [Bellard's refinement of Plouffe's algorithm](http://bellard.org/pi/pi_n2/pi_n2.html), with a somewhat more straightforward description of the refined algorithm
- [Gourdon's completely different algorithm](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/nthdecimaldigit.pdf#4) has a section dedicated to describing the completely different algorithm

Answer (score 0):

A known result related to $\pi$ and your expression is :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,2^n\,n!^2}{(2n)!}=\pi+3$$

Gery Huvent conjectured (equation $(401)$ from this excellent [$\pi$ site](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php)) that 
$$\forall k\ge 0,\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^k\,2^n\,n!^2}{(2n)!}=a_k\,\pi+b_k\quad\text{with}\;\frac {b_k}{a_k}\to\pi$$

The fractions $\dfrac {b_k}{a_k}$ obtained for the first values of $k$ are :
\begin{array} {l|cc}
k&&\frac {b_k}{a_k}\\
\hline
1&\frac 31&=&3\\
2&\frac {11}{7/2}&=&\frac {22}7\\
3&\frac{55}{35/2}&=&\frac {22}7\\
4&\frac{355}{113}&=&\frac{355}{113}\\
\end{array}

Comment: More general results are given in this [SE thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784843).