# Closed form for $ S(m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n \cdot n^m}{\binom{2n}n} $ for integer $m$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta, hypergeometric-function, pattern-recognition, catalan-numbers

What is the (simple) closed form for $\large \displaystyle S(m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^m}{\binom{2n}n} $ for integer $m$?

Notation: $ \dbinom{2n}n $ denotes the central binomial coefficient, $ \dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} $.

---

We have the following examples (all verified by WolframAlpha) for $ m\geq 0$:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
S(0) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n }{\binom{2n}n} = 2+ \dfrac{\pi}2 \\
S(1) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n }{\binom{2n}n} = 3+ \pi \\
S(2) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^2 }{\binom{2n}n} = 11+ \dfrac{7\pi}2 \\
S(3) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^3 }{\binom{2n}n} = 55+ \dfrac{35\pi}2 \\
S(4) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^4 }{\binom{2n}n} = 355 + 113\pi \approx \underline{709.9999}698 \ldots , \quad \text{So close to an integer? Coincidence?} \\
S(5) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^5 }{\binom{2n}n} = 2807+ \dfrac{1787\pi}2 \\
S(6) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^6 }{\binom{2n}n} = 26259+ \dfrac{16717\pi}2 \\
S(7) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \cdot n^7 }{\binom{2n}n} = 283623+ 90280\pi \\
\end{eqnarray} $$

And for $ m<0 $ as well (all verified by WolframAlpha as well):

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
S(-1) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \frac 1 n}{\binom{2n}n} = \dfrac{\pi}2 \\
S(-2) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \frac 1 {n^2} }{\binom{2n}n} = \dfrac{\pi^2 }8 \\
S(-3) &=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^n \frac 1 {n^3} }{\binom{2n}n} = \pi G - \dfrac{35\zeta(3)}{16} + \dfrac18 \pi^2 \ln2, \quad  G \text{ denotes Catalan's constant} \\
\end{eqnarray} $$

**So a natural question arise**: Is there a closed form for $S(m) $ for all integers $ m$?

---

For what it's worth, I couldn't get the (simple) closed form (using WolframAlpha alone) of $S(-4), S(-5), S(-6), \ldots $ and $ S(8), S(9) , \ldots $ without expressing it in terms of hypergeometric functions.

My question is: **Is there a closed form of $S(m) $ for all integers $m$ without using hypergeometric functions? And how do I compute all of these values?**

Note that I don't consider hypergeometric functions to be a "legitimate" function because it defeats the purpose of this question.

---

**My motivation**: I was trying to solve this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771881/show-that-sum-n-0-infty-frac2n5n55n45n35n2-9n92n12n2) and I decided to use the hint suggested by Mandrathrax, that is to use [partial fractions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions,+(5x%5E5%2B+5x%5E4+%2B+5x%5E3+%2B+5x%5E2+-9x%2B9)%2F((2x%2B1)(2x%2B2)(2x%2B3))) to get

$$ \dfrac{5n^5+5n^4+5n^3+5n^2-9n+9}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)} = \dfrac{5n^2}8 - \dfrac{5n}8 - \dfrac9{n+1} + \dfrac{457}{64(2n+1)} + \dfrac{135}{64(2n+3)} + \dfrac{85}{32} $$

So if I can prove the values of $ S(0), S(1), S(2) $ (which I failed to do so), then I'm pretty sure I'm halfway done with my solution.

Why do I still want to solve that question when it already has 21 upvotes? Because I think there's a simpler solution and I personally don't like to use polylogarithms.

---

**My feeble attempt (with help from my friends Aareyan and Julian) to solve my own question**: The Taylor series of $ (\arcsin x)^2  $ is $ \displaystyle \dfrac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2 \binom{2n}n} (2x)^n $. Differentiating with respect to $ x $ then multiply by $ x $ (repeatedly) gives some resemblance of $S(m)$, but these series only holds true for $|x| < 1$ and not $x=1$ itself. Now I'm stucked.

---

**EDIT1** (14 May 2016, 1101 GMT): Twice the coefficients of $\pi$ for $S(m)$ with $m\geq0$ appears to follow this [OEIS sequence, A014307](http://oeis.org/A014307).

**EDIT2** (14 May 2016, 1109 GMT): The constant for $S(m)$ with $m\geq1$ appears to follow this [OEIS sequence, A180875](http://oeis.org/A180875).

Comment: It is odd, but I just noticed that the coefficient of $\pi$ for $m=3,5$, when you divide them, it is almost the constant added to the $\pi$ terms divided.  Same for $m=5,6$ and $m=2,3$

Comment: Why is it that $S(1) = S(-2)$ and $S(2) = S(-3)$ in sum notation?

Comment: Suppose we solved the formula for the partial sums of $$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{2^ne^{nx}}{\binom{2n}n}$$If we differentiate this and the partial sum formula, we may be able to produce your problem.  Integrate for negative values of course, and take the limit to infinity to solve

Comment: I do not think this question has anything to do with the riemann-zeta function.  And I don't think pattern-recognition is the right tag either.  Perhaps the sequences and series tag may be more useful.

Comment: Consider $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{S(m)x^m}{m!}$ may be helpful.

Comment: You can  compute $S(0)$ using the Beta function.

Comment: Simple Art: I just added those tags because it was part of the requirement for posting this question.

Comment: @GohP.iHan: I updated my initial answer with rather simple generating functions that could interest you. Cheers,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(this answer is about negative values of $m$: the power of $n$)

We want for $m$ any positive integer :
$$\tag{1}S_{-m}(x) \equiv
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^m\binom{2n}{n}}$$

Let's start again [with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068) :
$$\tag{2}S_{-2}(x)=2\,\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$
Differentiation and multiplication by $\dfrac x2$ returns :
$$\tag{3}S_{-1}(x)=\frac x2\,S_2'(x)=2x\,\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}$$
While multiplication of $(1)$ by $\dfrac 2x$ and integration gives us :
$$\tag{4}S_{-3}(x)=\int_0^x \frac 4t\,\arcsin(t)^2\,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}$$
This integral may be expressed [using polylogarithms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(4%2Fx*arcsin(x)%5E2,x)) but it will be more convenient to write it using (real) [Clausen functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html) :
$$\tag{5}\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-1}(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n^{2m-1}},\;\operatorname{Cl}_{2m}(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n\,x)}{n^{2m}}$$
These functions appear in the [Fourier series from jump discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121376/21783) (their [variants are Bernoulli polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1210687/21783)) and are obtained from successive integrations of $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Cl}_1(x)=-\log\left(2\sin\frac x2\right)\;$ using $$\tag{6}\displaystyle\operatorname{Cl}_{2m}(x)=\int_0^x \operatorname{Cl}_{2m-1}(t)\,dt,\ \;\operatorname{Cl}_{2m+1}(x)=\zeta(2m+1)-\int_0^x \operatorname{Cl}_{2m}(t)\,dt$$

Let's set $\;t=\sin(u/2)\,$ and integrate by parts $\,\log(2\sin(u/2))\,$ to get  :
\begin{align}
S_{-3}(x)&=\int_0^x \frac 4t\,\arcsin(t)^2\,dt\\
&=4\int_0^{2\arcsin(x)} (u/2)^2\,\frac{\cos(u/2)}{2\,\sin(u/2)}\,du\\
&=\left.u^2\log(2\sin(u/2))\right|_0^{2\arcsin(x)}-\int_0^{2\arcsin(x)} 2\,u\log(2\,\sin(u/2))\,du\\
\end{align}

This becomes $\quad\displaystyle S_{-3}(x)=\,-2\log(2x)\,\operatorname{Ls}_2^{(1)}(2\arcsin(x))+2\,\operatorname{Ls}_3^{(1)}(2\arcsin(x))\;$

using Leonard Lewin's notation $(7.14)$ for the *generalized log-sine integral* $\;\operatorname{Ls}$ :
(Lewin $1981$ "Polylogaritms and associated functions" and [Kalmykov and Sheplyakov's $2004$](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0411100))

$$\tag{7}\operatorname{Ls}_j^{(k)}(x)=-\int_0^x t^k\,\left(\log\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)\right)^{j-k-1}dt,\quad k\ge 0,\ j\ge k+1\\  
\text{(or simply }\;\operatorname{Ls}_j(x)\;\text{for $k=0$)}$$

What makes the rewriting of $S_{-3}$ interesting is that it may be generalized to any $\,S_{-m}\,$ as shown by Borwein, Broadhurst and Kamnitzer $2001$ ["Central binomial sums, multiple Clausen values, and zeta values"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0004153). The derivation is rather clever (little typo : $\Gamma(n)$ should be $\Gamma(k)$) and will be reproduced in details and slightly generalized as in Kalmykov and Veretin $2000$ :

The [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is defined by $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(m):=\int_0^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-t}\,dt=\int_0^\infty (nt)^{m-1}e^{-nt}\,d(nt),\;(n>0)$
The substitution $\;t=-\log u\;$ gives $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(m)=n^m\int_0^1 (-\log u)^{m-1}\,u^{n-1}\,du\;$ so that for $\;u:=y^2$ :

\begin{align}
S_{-m}(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}\,n^m}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}\,\Gamma(m)}\int_0^1 (-2\log y)^{m-1}y^{2n-2}\,d(y^2)\\
&= \frac{(-2)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1 (\log y)^{m-1}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2x)^{2n}\frac{2\,y^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\,dy\\
&= -\frac{(-2)^{m-1}}{(m-2)!}\int_0^1 \frac{(\log y)^{m-2}}y\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2xy)^{2n}}{n\,\binom{2n}{n}}\,dy,\quad\text{(by parts)}\\
&=-\frac{(-2)^{m-1}}{(m-2)!}\int_0^1 (\log y)^{m-2}\frac{(2x)\,\arcsin(xy)}{\sqrt{1-(xy)^2}}\,dy,\quad\text{(using}\;S_{-1}(xy)\;\\
&=-\frac{(-2)^{m-1}}{(m-2)!}\int_0^{2\arcsin x} \left(\log\left(\frac 1x\sin\frac t2\right)\right)^{m-2}\frac t2\,dt,\quad\text{(setting}\;xy=\sin\frac t2\;\text{)}\\
\tag{8}S_{-m}(x)&= \frac 1{(m-2)!}\int_0^{2\arcsin x}\left[2\log(2x)-2\log\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)\right]^{m-2}\;t\;dt\\
\tag{9} S_{-m}(x)&= - \sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \frac{(-2)^j}{(m-2-j)!j!}
 \,\left(2 \log(2x)\right)^{m-2-j}\, \operatorname{Ls}_{j+2}^{(1)}\left(2\arcsin x\right)\\
\end{align}

Nan-Yue and Williams gave $(8)$ for $x=\dfrac 12$ in $1995$ ["Values of the Riemann zeta function and integrals involving $\log\left(2\sinh\frac{\theta}2\right)$ and $\log\left(2\sin\frac{\theta}2\right)$"](http://msp.org/pjm/1995/168-2/pjm-v168-n2-p04-p.pdf).
The general identities $(8)$ and $(9)$ (with a link to BBK's paper) were given in :

- Kalmykov and Veretin $2000$ ["Single scale diagrams and multiple binomial sums"](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0004010) $(8)$ and
- Davydychev and Kalmykov $2001$ ["New results for the $\epsilon$-expansion of certain one-, two- and three-loop Feynman diagrams"](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0012189).

The KV $2000$ paper contains too an additional intriguing formula using [Nielsen's generalized polylogarithm](http://cds.cern.ch/record/147790)  $\;\displaystyle \operatorname{S}_{n,p}(z):=\frac {(-1)^{n+p-1}}{(n-1)!p!}\int_0^1 \log^{n-1}(t)\,\log^p(1-zt)\,\frac{dt}t\;$ that I'll rewrite using $\,\operatorname{S}_{m-2,1}(z)=\operatorname{Li}_{m-1}(z)\,$ as :
$$\tag{10}S_{-m}(x)=\int_0^1\operatorname{Li}_{m-1}\left((2x)^2\,s(1-s)\right)\,\frac {ds}s$$
This formula is interesting too to evaluate $\;S_{+m}(x)\;$ ([rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) are integrated).
$$-$$
Now that $(9)$ allows us to express $\,S_{-m}(x)\,$ as "generalized log-sine integrals" $\operatorname{Ls}_m^{(1)}\,$ what can we do with that?

$\;\operatorname{Ls}_2^{(0)}(x)\;$ is simply the "Clausen integral" $\,\operatorname{Cl}_{2}(x)\,$ while (from Lewin's book $1981$ "Polylogaritms and associated functions" p. $200$) $\,\operatorname{Ls}_{n+2}^{(n)}(x)\,$ may be written as a sum of Clausen functions :

\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m-2)!}\int_0^x t^{2m-2}\log\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)dt&=\operatorname{Cl}_{2m}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-2k+1}(x)+\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-2k}(x)\right)\\
\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(2m-1)!}\int_0^x t^{2m-1}\log\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)dt&=\zeta(2m+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-2k+1}(x)+\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-2k}(x)\right)\\
\end{align}

Concerning your specific choice of $\;x=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\;$ (so that $\,\displaystyle 2\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}2\,$ and $\,2\log(2x)=\log(2)$) some explicit results were given in DK $2001$ (appendix A) that I complete here :

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Ls}_{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;\beta(2)\\
\operatorname{Ls}_{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;2\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac {1+i}2\right)+\beta(2)\log(2)-\tfrac{23}{192}\pi^3-\tfrac 1{16}\pi\log^2(2)\\
\operatorname{Ls}_{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;6\,\Im \,\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\tfrac {1+i}2\right) + 3\,\Im \,\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac {1+i}2\right)\log(2) - \tfrac 32\beta(4) + \tfrac 34\beta(2)\log^2(2) + \tfrac 34\pi\zeta(3) - \tfrac 1{16}\pi\log^3(2)\\
\hline
\operatorname{Ls}_{2}^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;-\tfrac{1}8\pi^2\\
\operatorname{Ls}_{3}^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;\;\tfrac{1}2 \pi\,\beta(2)-\tfrac{35}{32}\zeta(3)\\
\operatorname{Ls}_{4}^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;-\tfrac{5}{96} \log^4(2)+\tfrac{5}{16} \zeta(2) \log^2(2) - \tfrac{35}{32} \zeta(3) \log(2)
+ \tfrac{125}{32} \zeta(4) + \tfrac{1}{2} \pi \operatorname{Ls}_{3}\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)- \tfrac{5}{4} \operatorname{Li}_{4}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\\  
\operatorname{Ls}_{5}^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =&\;-\tfrac{1}{16} \log^5(2)
+ \tfrac{5}{16} \zeta(2) \log^3(2)- \tfrac{105}{128} \zeta(3) \log^2(2)
- \tfrac{15}{8} \operatorname{Li}_{4}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \log(2) - \tfrac{9}{8} \zeta(2) \zeta(3)
\nonumber \\
&\quad + \tfrac{1}{2} \pi \operatorname{Ls}_{4}\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)
- \tfrac{1209}{256} \zeta(5)
- \tfrac{15}{8} \operatorname{Li}_{5}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
allowing us (thanks to [Hypergeometric](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/628759)'s powerful comments) to extend the OP's table using only the common special functions :
\begin{align}S(-4)=&\;-2\pi\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac {1+i}2\right)  + \tfrac 52\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\tfrac 12\right) + \tfrac{19}{576}\pi^4 + \tfrac 1{48}\pi^2\log^2(2)  + \tfrac 5{48}\log^4(2)\\
S(-5)=&\;4 \pi\,\Im\,\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\tfrac{1+i}{2}\right)-\tfrac{5}{2} \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)+\tfrac 14{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}-\tfrac{403}{64} \zeta (5)-\pi\,\beta\left(4\right)+\tfrac 1{48}{\log ^5(2)}+\tfrac{1}{144} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)+\tfrac{19}{576} \pi ^4 \log (2)\\
\end{align}
$$-$$
In Davydychev and Kalmykov $2004$ ["Massive Feynman diagrams and inverse binomial sums"](http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/0303162) one finds some general results ($\,z$ is our $(2x)^2\,$) :

For $\;\displaystyle\theta:=2\,\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}2\right),\ l_{\theta}:=\log\left(2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\;$ we have :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n}  
&=  \theta\,\tan\frac{\theta}{2}&\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^2} 
&=\frac{1}{2}\,\theta^2 &\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^4} 
&= - 2 \operatorname{Ls}_{4}^{(1)}(\theta)+ 4 l_{\theta}
\left[\operatorname{Cl}_3(\theta) + \theta \operatorname{Cl}_2(\theta) - \zeta(3) \right] 
+\theta^2 l_{\theta}^2 &\\
\end{align}

For the conformal variable $\;\displaystyle y:=\frac{\sqrt{z-4}-\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z-4}+\sqrt{z}}\;$ we have :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n}  & = 
\frac{1-y}{1+y}\;\log(y)\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^2} & = -\frac{1}{2}\;\log^2(y)\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^3} & = 
2 \operatorname{Li}_3(y) - 2\;\log(y)\,\operatorname{Li}_{2}(y) - \log^2(y)\, \log(1-y) 
+ \frac{1}{6}\,\log^3(y)- 2 \zeta(3) \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^4} & =  
  4 \operatorname{S}_{2,2}(y)
- 4 \operatorname{Li}_{4}(y) - 4 \operatorname{S}_{1,2}(y) \log(y) 
+ 4 \operatorname{Li}_{3}(y) \log(1-y) \\
&+ 2 \operatorname{Li}_3(y) \log(y) - 4 \operatorname{Li}_{2}(y) \log(y) \log(1-y) - \log^2(y) \log^2(1-y) 
\\
&+ \frac{1}{3} \log^3(y)\log(1-y) - \frac{1}{24} \log^4(y) 
- 4 \log(1-y)  \zeta(3) + 2 \log(y) \zeta(3)+ 3 \zeta(4)
\end{align}

Comment: THANKYOUUUUU!! It will take me decades to understand everything here.

Comment: Glad you liked all that and Thanks again for the (too) generous bounty! Note that you shouldn't have to learn particle physics i.e. Feynman diagrams first to digest all that! :-) Anyway should you have any question about this answer don't hesitate to ask here. I'll try to answer in the comments or... add that in my next edit! Cheers,

Comment: Those inverse binomial sums are interesting. I just came across something similar with log sine integrals.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: Central binomial sums and log sine integrals are fun indeed. Boris Gourévitch has a page about such series [here](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php) (he found a related BBP sum for $\zeta(3)$ in $2000$ and I also played much with such series in these years). Cheers,

Comment: All $\text{Ls}_n^{(k)}(\pi/2)$ where $k=0,1$, as well as $2$ classes of corresponding hypergeometric series, are evaluable via level 4 Multiple Zeta Values. See Thm $2$ of [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.02508).

Comment: The last formula is impressive, which can be used to establish the golden-ratio polylog-ladder of generalized Apery series if $z=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for these informations @User. I'll have to look at all that in detail. Excellent continuation,

Comment: The $z=-1$ case: $$\small \, _5F_4\left(1,1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2,2;-\frac{1}{4}\right)=-\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+16 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right)-8 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \text{csch}^{-1}(2)+8 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right) \text{csch}^{-1}(2)-\frac{7 \pi ^4}{45}+\frac{2}{3} \pi ^2 \text{csch}^{-1}(2)^2+\frac{1}{3} \text{csch}^{-1}(2)^3 \left(4 \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-17 \text{csch}^{-1}(2)\right)$$

Comment: A Logsine integral example: $$\small \, _6F_5\left(1,1,1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2,2,2;\frac{1}{2}\right)=4 \pi  \Im\left(\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{5 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{4}-\frac{403 \zeta (5)}{64}-\frac{1}{256} \pi  \zeta \left(4,\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{256} \pi  \zeta \left(4,\frac{3}{4}\right)+\frac{\log ^5(2)}{48}+\frac{1}{144} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)+\frac{19}{576} \pi ^4 \log (2)$$ See more in the link.

Comment: Two neat results indeed! The first one may be nicely rewritten using the golden ratio $o$ and its powers (and $\operatorname{csch}^{-1}(2)=\log(o)$) with the last term simply $-3\;\operatorname{csch}^{-1}(2)^4=-3\log(o)^4$. In your second result you may replace the two Hurwitz zeta terms simply by $-\pi\,\beta(4)$ (the Dirichlet beta function which could be useful for higher order generalizations!). Your [summary of MZV identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800666) is very interesting too!

Comment: Other arguments: $$\small \, _8F_7\left(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2,2,2,2,2;\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{17 \pi ^4 \zeta (3)}{810}+\frac{2 \pi ^2 \zeta (5)}{3}-\frac{493 \zeta (7)}{12}+\frac{\pi  \left(\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)-\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\right)}{311040 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: $$\small \, _7F_6\left(1,1,1,1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2,2,2,2;-\frac{1}{8}\right)=-8 \zeta(\bar 5,1)+64 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+24 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)+4 \zeta (3)^2-\frac{4}{3} \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)+38 \zeta (5) \log (2)-\frac{\pi ^6}{14}-\frac{1}{180} 19 \log ^6(2)+\frac{1}{9} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)-\frac{7}{90} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$$

Comment: Generally, for $_pF_{p-1}(\{1\}_p;\frac32, \{2\}_{p-2};z)$, as $z=1, -1/8$ one have level 2 MZVs, $z=1/2$ level 4, $z=-1/4$ level 5, $z=1/4$ level 6 (and conjecturally $z=-1$ level 8).  This kind of hypergeometric series is intimately related to MZVs, but my knowledge is limited for now.

Comment: Thanks for these results too @Hypergeometric! For people reading all this :$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left( 2n \atop n\right) } \frac{z^n}{n^{\,p}}=\frac  z2\; _{p+1}F_{p}\left(\{1\}_{p+1};\frac32, \{2\}_{p-1};\frac z4\right)$$

Comment: Another simplification : $\frac{\pi  \left(\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)-\psi ^{(5)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\right)}{311040 \sqrt{3}}=12\,\pi\, \operatorname{Cl}_6\left(\frac {\pi}3\right)$

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE 2017/10**

We want the closed form for $\,\displaystyle S_m(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^m (2x)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\,$ for nonnegative $m$ and will start with the [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068) expression for $m=-2$ :

$$\tag{1}F(x):=2\,\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}=S_{-2}(x)$$ 
From this we deduce :
\begin{align}
F'(x)&=4\,\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n-1}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}\\
(x\,F'(x))'&=4\,\frac{\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1)+x}{1-x^2}&=8\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
(x\,(x\,F'(x))')'&=4\,\frac{\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1+2x^2)+3x}{(1-x^2)^2}&=16\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\;(2x)^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&4\,\frac{\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1+10x^2+4x^4)+7x+8x^3}{(1-x^2)^3}&=32\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2\;(2x)^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&4\,\frac{\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1+36x^2+60x^4+8x^6)+15x+70x^3+20x^5}{(1-x^2)^4}&=64\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3\;(2x)^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&\cdots
\end{align}
Of course the idea is to take $\;x=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\,$ and obtain your results after multiplication by $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{m+3}}\,$ if $m$ is the power of $n$ at the numerator.

A pattern seems to emerge from these laborious computations. Let's begin with :
$$\tag{2}F_{m-1}(x):=\frac{a(x)P(x)+Q(x)}{(1-x^2)^m}$$
where $\,P(x),\;Q(x)\,$ are two polynomials while $\ a(x):=\dfrac {\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;$ so that $\ a(x)'=\dfrac{x\,a(x)+1}{1-x^2}$.

The derivative of $\,(x\;F_{m-1}(x))\,$ will then be given by :
\begin{align}
&=\frac{a(x)P(x)+Q(x)}{(1-x^2)^m}+x\left(\frac{a(x)P(x)+Q(x)}{(1-x^2)^m}\right)'\\
&=\frac{(a(x)P(x)+Q(x))\left(1+\dfrac{2mx^2}{1-x^2}\right)+x\left(a(x)'P(x)+a(x)P(x)'+Q(x)'\right)}{(1-x^2)^m}\\
&=\frac{(a(x)P(x)+Q(x))\left(1+\dfrac{2mx^2}{1-x^2}\right)+\dfrac{x^2\,a(x)+x}{1-x^2}P(x)+x(a(x)P(x)'+Q(x)')}{(1-x^2)^m}\\
&=\frac{(a(x)P(x)+Q(x))\left(1+(2m-1)x^2\right)+(x^2\,a(x)+x)P(x)+(x-x^3)(a(x)P(x)'+Q(x)')}{(1-x^2)^{m+1}}\\
&=\frac{a(x)\left[P(x)\left(1+2mx^2\right)+(x-x^3)P(x)'\right]+xP(x)+\left(1+(2m-1)x^2\right)Q(x)+(x-x^3)Q(x)'}{(1-x^2)^{m+1}}\\
\end{align}

which follows clearly our $(2)$ pattern with the recurrence for the polynomials (starting with $\;P_0(x)=1,\;Q_0(x)=x$) given by :
\begin{align}
\tag{3}P_m(x)&=P_{m-1}(x)\left(1+2mx^2\right)+(x-x^3)P_{m-1}(x)'\\
Q_m(x)&=x\,P_{m-1}(x)+\left(1+(2m-1)x^2\right)Q_{m-1}(x)+(x-x^3)Q_{m-1}(x)'\\
\end{align}
From this recurrence we obtain :
$$\tag{4}\boxed{\displaystyle\frac{a(x)P_m(x)+Q_m(x)}{(2\,(1-x^2))^{m+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^m\;(2x)^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac {S_m(x)}{2x}},\quad a(x)=\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ 
that you may apply to your specific case $\;x=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\,$ for which $\;a(x)=\dfrac {\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\,$ and $\,(2\,(1-x^2))=1\,$ (of course the $\sqrt{2}$ terms disappear after multiplication by $\,2x$ ).
$$-$$
We didn't use the fact that $P(x),\;Q(x)$ were polynomials. Let's do that and suppose that $P_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m p_k\,x^{2k},\;Q_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m q_k\,x^{2k+1}$ then $(3)$ becomes :

\begin{align}
P_m(x)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, x^{2k}\right)\left(1+2mx^2\right)+(x-x^3)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, x^{2k}\right)'\\
Q_m(x)&=x\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, x^{2k}\right)+\left(1+(2m-1)x^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q_k\, x^{2k+1}\right)+(x-x^3)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q_k\, x^{2k+1}\right)'\\
\end{align}
Starting with $P_m(x)$ :
\begin{align}
P_m(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, x^{2k}+2m\sum_{k=1}^{m} p_{k-1}\, x^{2k} +\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, 2k\,x^{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} p_{k-1}\, 2(k-1)\,x^{2k}\\
&=p_0+(2m-2(m-1))\,p_{m-1}x^{2m}+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \left(p_k+2m\,p_{k-1}+p_k 2k-p_{k-1}\, 2(k-1)\right)\,x^{2k}\\
&=p_0+2\,p_{m-1}x^{2m}+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \left((2k+1)\,p_k+2(m-k+1)\,p_{k-1}\right)\,x^{2k}\\
\end{align}

The coefficients $p_k(m)$ of $P_m(x)$ may thus be obtained from the coefficients  $p_k(m-1)$ of $P_{m-1}(x)$ (beginning with $\,p_0(m)=1\,$ since $p_0$ is the only $x^0$ term) :
$$\tag{5}p_k(m)=\begin{cases}
k=0 & 1 \\
0<k<m& 2(m-k+1)\,p_{k-1}(m-1)+(2k+1)\,p_k(m-1)\\
k=m & 2\,p_k(m-1)\\
\text{else}& 0
\end{cases}
$$
We may illustrate this by showing how the first coefficients $p_k(m)$ (in blue) were obtained
($k$ is indicated as $\,(k)\,$ in its appropriate diagonal) :
$$
\begin{array} {c|ccccccccccc}
m&&&&&&&\color{blue}{p_k}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&(0)\\
0&&&&&&&\color{blue}{1}\\
&&&&&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 1}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times 2}&&(1)\\
1&&&&&\color{blue}{1}&&&&\color{blue}{2}\\
&&&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 1}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times 4}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 3}&& \rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times2}&&(2)\\
2&&&\color{blue}{1}&&&&\color{blue}{10}&&&&\color{blue}{4}\\
&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 1}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times6}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 3}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times 4}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\swarrow}}\scriptsize{\ \ \ \times 5}&&\rlap{\LARGE{\searrow}}\scriptsize {\times2}&&(3)\\
3&\color{blue}{1}&&&&\color{blue}{36}&&&&\color{blue}{60}&&&&\color{blue}{8}\\
\end{array}
$$
$\qquad\qquad\quad p_2(3)=\color{blue}{60}\,$ for example was obtained as $\;4\times \color{blue}{10}+5\times \color{blue}{4}$.

Concerning $Q_m(x)$ :
\begin{align}
Q_m(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} p_k\, x^{2k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q_k\, x^{2k+1}+(2m-1)\sum_{k=1}^{m} q_{k-1}\, x^{2k+1}\\&\quad+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} q_k\, (2k+1)\,x^{2k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m} q_{k-1}\, (2k-1)\,x^{2k+1}\\
&=(p_0+2q_0)x+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(p_k+q_k+(2m-1)\,q_{k-1}+q_k\, (2k+1)-q_{k-1}\,(2k-1)\right)\,x^{2k+1}\\
&=(1+2q_0)x+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(p_k+2(m-k)\,q_{k-1}+2(k+1)\,q_k\right)\,x^{2k+1}\\
\end{align}
$$\tag{6}q_k(m)=\begin{cases}
k=0 & \begin{cases} m=0 & 1 \\m>0&1+2\,q_0(m-1) \\ \end{cases}\\
0<k<m& p_k(m-1)+2(m-k)\,q_{k-1}(m-1)+2(k+1)\,q_k(m-1)\\
\text{else}&0
\end{cases}$$

These results were obtained earlier by D.H. Lehmer in ["Interesting Series Involving the Central Binomial"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322496) ([pdf here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,622040,622040) "télécharger" Lehmer_binom.pdf).

The $p_k(m)$ triangle appears too in [OEIS A156919](https://oeis.org/A156919) and in Savage and Viswanathan's paper ["The $1/k$-Eulerian Polynomials"](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~savage/PAPERS/The_1_over_k_Eulerian_Polynomials.pdf) (for $k:=2$) and following generating function is provided ([Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series(sqrt((1-x)%2F(exp(2*z*(x-1))-x)),z))) :
\begin{align}
\tag{7}\sqrt{\frac {1-y}{\exp(2z(y-1))-y}}&=\sum_{n\ge 0}A_n^{(2)}(y)\frac {z^n}{n!}\\
&=1+z+(1+2y)\frac{z^2}{2!}+(1+10y+4y^2)\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots
\end{align}

In your specific case $\,y=x^2=\dfrac 12$ this becomes this exponential generating function (e.g.f.) :
$$\tag{8}\frac 1{\sqrt{2\exp(-z)-1}}=1+1z+2\frac{z^2}{2!}+7\frac{z^3}{3!}+35\frac{z^4}{4!}+226\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
([OEIS A014307](https://oeis.org/A014307): *exactly your numerators $\;1,2,7,35,226,\cdots\;$ for the $\dfrac {\pi}2$ terms!*)
$$-$$

**2017 ADDITION:**

Your integer sequence $\;1,3,11,55,355,\cdots$ is known too ([OEIS A180875](https://oeis.org/A180875)) but with no indicated generating function. An idea to get this one is to obtain the exponential generating function for the complete $S_m(x)$ terms first (subtracting $\frac {\pi}2$ times $(8)$ should then return the wished e.g.f. and sequence).

Let's multiply $(4)$ by $\;\displaystyle (2x)(2\,(1-x^2))^{m+1}\frac{z^m}{m!}\;$ and sum over $m$ to get :
\begin{align}
G_x(z)&:=(2x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(a(x)P_m(x)+Q_m(x)\right)\frac{z^m}{m!}\tag{9}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty S_m(x) \left(2\left(1-x^2\right)\right)^{m+1}\frac{z^m}{m!}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^m\;(2x)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}} \left(2\left(1-x^2\right)\right)^{m+1}\frac{z^m}{m!}\\
&=2\left(1-x^2\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}} \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\left(2n\left(1-x^2\right)z\right)^m}{m!}\\
&=2\left(1-x^2\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}\,\exp\left(2n\left(1-x^2\right)z\right)}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&=2\left(1-x^2\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(2x\exp\left(\left(1-x^2\right)z\right)\right)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&=2\left(1-x^2\right)S_0(u),\quad\text{for}\ \,u:=x\exp\left(\left(1-x^2\right)z\right)\\
G_x(z)&=2\left(1-x^2\right)u\,\frac{\large{\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}}+u}{1-u^2}\tag{10}\\
\end{align}
since in our third equation $\,\displaystyle\frac x4(x\,F'(x))'\,$ gives 
$\;\displaystyle S_0(u)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2u)^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=u\,\frac{\large{\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}}+u}{1-u^2}$.

From the definition $(9)$ we may then use $(10)$ to evaluate for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the terms :
$$\tag{11}(2x)\left(a(x)P_m(x)+Q_m(x)\right)=S_m(x)\left(2\left(1-x^2\right)\right)^{m+1}=\left.\left(\frac d{dz}\right)^m\right|_{z=0} G_x(z)$$
(the e.g.f. of the sole $\,S_m(x)$ terms is obtained by preferring $\;u:=x\,\exp(z/2)\;$)

In our specific case $\,x=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\,$ we have $\,u=\dfrac {\exp(z/2)}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $(10)$ and $(11)$ become :
\begin{align}
\tag{12}G_{\large{\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}}}(z)&=\frac{\large{u\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}}+u^2}{1-u^2}=\frac{{2\exp(z/2)}\frac{\arcsin(\exp(z/2)/\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2-\exp(z)}}+\exp(z)}{2-\exp(z)}\\
S_m\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)&=\frac{\pi}2 P_m\left(\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sqrt{2}\,Q_m\left(\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
\tag{13}&=\left.\left(\frac d{dz}\right)^m\right|_{z=0} \frac{{2\exp(z/2)}\frac{\arcsin(\exp(z/2)/\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2-\exp(z)}}+\exp(z)}{2-\exp(z)}\\
\tag{14}&=\left.\left(\frac d{dz}\right)^{m+1}\right|_{z=0} \frac{{2\exp(z/2)}\arcsin(\exp(z/2)/\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2-\exp(z)}}\\
\tag{15}&=\left.\left(\frac d{dz}\right)^{m+2}\right|_{z=0} 2\arcsin^2\left(\frac{\exp(z/2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&\text{(integrating twice at the end)}\\
\end{align}

The last equation provides a very nice method to obtain all the $S(m)$ terms in the question
(btw $\,S(0)=1+\frac {\pi}2\,$ rather than $\,2+\frac {\pi}2\,$) :

- expand $\;\displaystyle 2\arcsin^2\left(\frac{\exp(z/2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ in series :
  $$2\arcsin^2\left(\frac{\exp(z/2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}8+\frac{\pi}2z+\left(\frac {\pi}2+1\right)\frac{z^2}{2!}+\left(\frac{2\pi}2+3\right)\frac{z^3}{3!}+\left(\frac{7\pi}2+11\right)\frac{z^4}{4!}+\left(\frac{35\pi}2+55\right)\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
- and compute the second derivative **or** *simply ignore the two first terms and shift by $2$ the remaining ones!*

Concerning an e.g.f. for $\;1,3,11,55,\cdots$ we will rewrite $(14)$ and combine it with $(8)$ to get :
$$\frac{{2}\arcsin(\exp(z/2)/\sqrt{2})-\large{\frac {\pi}2}}{\sqrt{2\exp(-z)-1}}=1z+3\frac{z^2}{2!}+11\frac{z^3}{3!}+55\frac{z^4}{4!}+355\frac{z^5}{5!}+2807\frac{z^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

---

For an explicit general solution (instead of the recursive method provided) see this neat paper by the masters :

- **Dyson, Frankel and Glasser ["Lehmer's Interesting Series"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4274)**
  where they obtain following expression $(20)$ for $\;\displaystyle S_k(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^kz^n}{{2n \choose n}}\;$ :

$$\tag{16}S_k(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} n! \left({\frac{z}{4-z}}\right)^n\ E(k,n)\\
\left[\frac{1}{n} + \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} (-1)^p 
\frac{({\frac{1}{2}})_p}{(p+1)!}\ C^{n-1}_p 
\left({\frac 4z}\right)^{p+1}
\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{z}{4-z}}\arcsin\left({\frac{\sqrt{z}}{2}}\right)- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{l=1}^p \frac{\Gamma(l)}{\left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)_l}
\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^l\right\}\right]$$

with $\;\displaystyle E(k,n) := \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^m\ C^{n}_m\ m^{k+1}$ the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
and $\left({\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)_l$ the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).
Comparing this to $(1)$ we see that $z=(2x)^2$ while $k=m$ (of course you want $z=2$ here).

This paper includes too your interesting observation about the ratios approaching $\pi$ (page $12$).

A subsequent paper by Glasser ($2012$) is ["A Generalized Apery Series"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1078).

Comment: From the last edit of the OP it seems that he already had the link to this paper making all this much less interesting...

Comment: Way to make you sound less smart

Comment: @SimpleArt: well the answer was already provided (by Dyson, Frankel and Glasser ) making this de facto less challenging...

Comment: Extremely detailed. Now what about negative integers $m$?

Comment: @GohP.iHan: Well the pattern is rather different and increasingly difficult. Another answer should deserve these cases (I'll try...)

Comment: Haha! I figured that much! Do you want me to post another separate question?

Comment: @GohP.iHan: No no, your question here is clear enough (I hope to add another answer this weekend but you shouldn't hold your breath concerning closed forms! ;-) )

Comment: Great! Once you're done, let me know and I'll start a bounty of 100 and give you that bounty!

Comment: @GohP.iHan: In fact this answer was CW but thanks for the proposition anyway (I like to put everything at one place). Cheers,

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this site. Which "answer" of yours should I reward?

Comment: @GohP.iHan: A post marked ["community wiki"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) belongs to the community so the other one if you want *or* a better one if somebody else got the focused answer you wished. My heavy answers shouldn't discourage better ones! Many thanks for the intention anyway,

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Many thanks for the very generous bounty added to my other answer (even if it makes me notice that things could be added, clarified... :-)). Concerning this answer note that I made it community wiki (it doesn't belong me anymore). Wishing you an excellent mathematical continuation at SE! Cheers,

Comment: Oh shoot, can I give bounties to CW's?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I think so (I will not be credited but I can live with that!) Thanks for the intention anyway,

Comment: :-) Always! And I too think it should work. (It has the button to give a bounty to this)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Sorry for your third place as a med. but this should give you more time to play with maths. Wishing you fun,

Comment: Thanks. Personally believe that third is a good place to be, and those elected are likewise pretty good. I'm happy, winning or not.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: First : I'm glad you see it that way (they are indeed good!). Many thanks for the second bounty and... for proving me wrong  (always a good thing if not abused! :-)) concerning the bounty credit. I'll try to improve a little my other answer this weekend or the following one. Very pleasant mathematical explorations,

Comment: That'd be amazing. Thank you regardless :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I updated this answer (instead of the other one) but hope this could be of interest too for your (too) generous bounty. All the best,